# How does my PHP recognise whether it is running via Docker or Xampp?

Tags: docker, dynamic, xampp

I have a PHP login system that should be built to run on both XAMPP and Docker at the same time. My database need to be localy stored.

I create my Container and Image like these:

Image: docker build -t php . Container: docker run -dp 9000:80 --name php-app php

```
<?php
$host = "host.docker.internal"; // need to be that or 'localhost'
$name = "test";
$user = "root";
$passwort = "";
try {
    $mysql = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$name", $user, $passwort);
}

catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo "SQL Error: ".$e->getMessage();
}
```

?>

Where do I get the information on which system I am running to make this value dynamic?

Comment: Are enviroment Variables the way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3):

You can check if you are inside Docker this way:

```php
function isDocker(): bool
{
    return is_file("/.dockerenv");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't worked on windows system yet but in Linux, You can check the processes and find process execute using docker or not.

```
$processes = explode(PHP_EOL, shell_exec('cat /proc/self/cgroup'));
// Check process folder path and pass here
$processes = array_filter($processes);
$is_docker = true;
foreach ($processes as $process) {
    if (strpos($process, 'docker') === false) {
        $is_docker = false;
    }
}
```

Then you can implement as per your need.

```
if($is_docker === true){
    // Do something
}
```